# C# WPF Convert byte array to image - getting slower over time - Why?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following function to convert a byte array to a BitmapSource:

```
public static BitmapSource GetImageFromByteArray(byte[] imageBytes) {
    if(imageBytes == null || imageBytes.Length == 0) return null;
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using(var mem = new MemoryStream(imageBytes)) {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit();
    }
    image.Freeze();
    return image;            
}
```

The function is working fine for some time. After working about 5 hours with the app this function was called very often and suddenly it starts getting very slow. In the case of one user it took 6 Seconds (not Milliseconds!) to finish for a jpg with the size of 100x100. And it stays that slow. E.g.: Displaying a List with 10 little images (Logos) is taking suddenly 1 Minute!

Using dotTrace on this problem is definitely showing this functions as the cause of the problem.

The created images are getting collected by the GC as soon as the WPF Window is closed. So this looks good.

What is wrong with this function? Do I miss anything?

Comment: Besides the redundant `mem.Position = 0;` and `image.UriSource = null;` statements, the method looks ok. You may however just use the built-in typeconverter, like `var image = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(imageBytes);`.

Comment: Hi Clemens. I take new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(imageBytes);. as an answer. This is also running very much faster. I hope it stays faster over time. I will post the results if not. If you write it as an answer I can accept it.... Thanks!